# Mac Bash Command Not Found for Pagekite Signup

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal

I have been following the Pagekite installation for Mac at (https://pagekite.net/support/quickstart/).

**Here are the instructions I have followed:**

1. First I download the program (pagekite.py) and I put it into my sites folder.
2. Next I attempt to run Pagekite.py for the first time by running the following command

   `$ pagekite.py --signup`

   but I can only get to step 2 before I get the error:

`-bash $: command not found`

I'll admit I am quite new at troubleshooting terminal commands, so if I left out any information let me know.
See below-attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: what is the command you entered?

Comment: don't expect readers to goto external sites to understand your problem. Can't you copy/paste the info for Installation Error into the Q? Use `{}` on the edit tool bar on selected text to format as code/data/error messages. Good luck.

Comment: You have included the `$`...that stands for the prompt. Copy-paste the commands to your console without the initial symbol `$`.

Answer (score 1):

You have included the `$`...that stands for the prompt. Copy-paste the commands to your console without the initial symbol `$`.
                    – thanasisp